# Does it make sense to use Hibernate clear method and then rollback?

Tags: hibernate, difference, rollback, between

I want to know if there is any difference between hibernate's session.clear method and rollback() method? I understand that session.clear() will clear objects from the session and rollback() will rollback whole transaction. My question is will there be any performance difference if I use both methods together - first call session.clear() method and then call session.rollback() method?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, what is the problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: @Tunaki - I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical transaction (pseudo-code):

```
try {
    Begin Transaction;
    update + flush
    update + flush
    throw Ex
    commit;
} catch Ex {
    rollback;
    // if you make rollback, clear is needed 
    clear;
}
```

Comment: Entitiies modified will be cached when flushed.

Comment: If you don't clear, it will be returned if you search it by PK.